# Automatic reply to SMS is not working. Android studio

Tags: java, broadcastreceiver, sendmessage

I am trying to send automatic reply when receiving sms using `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to sms and `SmsManager` to send reply but the auto reply is not working.
**Note:** If I call `smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);` from onCreate, it indeed sends a message but the problem is when I am trying to call it from `messageReceived`.
I have also tried to use `registerReceiver` instead `bindListener` but the same happened.

When running on emulator all Toasts are showing (but I can't really check that a message is sent on emulator). 
When running on device connected via USB cable, "sending the message" Toast is not showing.

I will really appreciate your help.
Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SmsListener, View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
             requestSMSPermission();
        }

        else{

            SmsReceiver.bindListener(this);
            Toast.makeText(this, "listening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }



    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String messageText, String sender) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sending the message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(sender, null, messageText, null, null);

    }


    private void requestSMSPermission(){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission needed").setMessage("This permission is needed in order to send automatic reply")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},READ_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();

    }
    else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},READ_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

}


}
```

Receiver class:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static SmsListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        String sender = null;
        for(int i=0; i<pdus.length; i++){
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            sender = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
            String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();

            mListener.messageReceived(messageBody,sender);

        }



    }

    public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


}
```

Listener interface:

```
public interface SmsListener {
    public void messageReceived(String messageText, String sender);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the problem;
This issue happens on api > 26 (maybe even 25).
On api 24 this code above worked just fine and an automatic reply was sent.
The problem is that I requested permission for `SEND_SMS` (in Manifest I have READ,RECEIVE,SEND) and apparently on api 26 it doesn't really give permission for `RECEIVE_SMS` so In my code **`onReceive` was never called**.

Solution: I have changed the permission above to `RECEIVE_SMS` and added to `onCreate` this:

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},111);
}
```

**To conclude:** If you want two (or more) permissions from the same family (e.g `READ_SMS/SEND_SMS`), you need to request for **all** needed permissions even thought eventually you will see a dialog only once allowing all permissions together.
In API <= 24 it is enough to request only for one permission from the same family (e.g `READ_SMS`) and you receive the rest